# ¿ como calcular la cantidad de días, meses y años que han pasado desde una fecha hasta el día de hoy?

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente  codigo:

```
    DateTime ffin ,fini ;
    ffin = DateTime.Today;
    fini = txtfingreso.Value;

     
         meses = System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.DateDiffMonth(fini ,ffin );
         dias = System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.DateDiffDay(fini , ffin );
        anios = System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.DateDiffYear(fini , ffin );
```

Teniendo como fecha de ingreso 03/08/2019 y al dia de hoy 5/10/2020

tengo el siguiente resultado: años=1, meses=14,dias = 429

Pero no es lo que quiero:
En este ejemplo necesito el siguiente resultado:  años=1, meses=1,dias = 28

que sería la cantidad de años, meses y dias que han pasado desde fini hasta hoy (ffin)

Comment: Podrias calcularlo de una manera manual de forma sencilla, pero tambien podrías usar alguna librería tipo NodaTime que ya tienen esos métodos implementados

Answer (score 0):

creo que lo solucione con esto:

```
 public string Edad(DateTime FechaNac)
    {
        int Años=0;
        int Meses=0;
        int Dias=0;
        DateTime FechaCalculo;

        FechaCalculo = FechaNac;

        if (FechaNac > DateTime.Today)
        {
          
            return "Error. Fecha futura";
        }

        while (FechaCalculo.AddYears(1) <= DateTime.Today) // comprobamos los años que ha cumplido
        {
            Años = Años + 1;
            FechaCalculo = FechaCalculo.AddYears(1); // añadiendo años a la fecha de nacimiento
        }

        while (FechaCalculo.AddMonths(1) <= DateTime.Today) // comprobamos los meses que ha cumplido
        {
            Meses = Meses + 1;
            FechaCalculo = FechaCalculo.AddMonths(1); // añadiendo meses
        }

        while (FechaCalculo.AddDays(1) <= DateTime.Today) // finalmente comprobamos los dias que ha cumplido
        {
            Dias = Dias + 1;
            FechaCalculo = FechaCalculo.AddDays(1);
        }

        txtaños.Text = Años.ToString();
        txtmeses.Text = Meses.ToString();
        txtdias.Text = (Dias+1).ToString();
        return   "";
    }
```

Comment: Hola por fin resolviste?

Comment: Si la respuesta ha resuelto tu problema, marca como aceptada: click en el check verde :)